# Center items in minipage environment

Tags: beamer, minipage

[image]

I dont understand why my items does not center in minipage.
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
}


\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usefonttheme{structurebold}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\usepackage{textpos}

\title[A.M. of Martensitic Steel]{Personal Research Work:\\ Additive Manufacturing of Martensitic Steel}

\author{CORONGIU Chiara}

\date{December 12, 2019}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}{Choice of the presentation subject}
\begin{minipage}{0.49\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{../TFE/images/pignon.png} 
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.49\linewidth}
\begin{center}
Surface material:
\begin{itemize}
\item Hard
\item Wear resistant
\item Corrosion resistant
\end{itemize}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

As you can see my 3 items are not centered and I cannot figure out why :/
Thanks in advance

Comment: A simple solution could be don't use `minipage`, but use absolute positioning with `textpos` package. See par 12.8 of beameruserguide. Probably even using columns can solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

`itemize` items are left aligned by default. To center them, `\centering` has to be repeated in the `itemize`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
}


\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usefonttheme{structurebold}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\usepackage{textpos}

\title[A.M. of Martensitic Steel]{Personal Research Work:\\ Additive Manufacturing of Martensitic Steel}

\author{CORONGIU Chiara}

\date{December 12, 2019}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}{Choice of the presentation subject}
\begin{minipage}{0.49\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image} 
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.49\linewidth}
\begin{center}
Surface material:

\begin{itemize}
\centering
\item Hard
\item Wear resistant
\item Corrosion resistant
\end{itemize}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Simply reasonable explanation!

Answer (score 1):

```
     \documentclass{beamer}

     \mode<presentation> {
     \usetheme{CambridgeUS}
     }


     \usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
     \usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
     \usepackage{todonotes}
     \usepackage{amsmath,bm}
     \usefonttheme{structurebold}
     \usepackage{ulem}
     \usepackage{fancybox}
     \usepackage{tikz}
     \usepackage{url}
     \usepackage{float}
     \usepackage{subfig}
     \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
     \usepackage[absolute,overlay
     %,showboxes
     ]{textpos}
     \TPGrid{1}{1}

     \title[A.M. of Martensitic Steel]{Personal Research Work:\\ Additive Manufacturing of Martensitic Steel}

     \author{CORONGIU Chiara}

     \date{December 12, 2019}

     \begin{document}
     \begin{frame}
     \titlepage
     \end{frame}

     \section{Introduction}

     \begin{frame}{Choice of the presentation subject}
     \begin{minipage}{0.49\linewidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a} 
     \end{minipage}
     \begin{textblock}{0.4}(0.6,0.4)
     Surface material:
     \begin{itemize}
     \item Hard
     \item Wear resistant
     \item Corrosion resistant
     \end{itemize}
     \end{textblock}
     \end{frame}
     \end{document}
```

[image]